# What happens same async function is called second time before finishing the first execution in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to understand following case in node.js,

let's say we have following:

```js
somefunction = (a) => {
  var b = a
  anAsyncFuntionThatTakes1to10SecondsRandomly(()=>{
    console.log(b)
  })
}
```

somefunction will be called upon an API request to an endpoint,

What happens if somefunction is twice in a row with different values, coming from different requests...

I tested below and works as expected, without interfering.

```
const somefunction = (a) => {
 var b = a
 timeoutFunc(()=>{
   console.log(b)
 })
}

const timeoutFunc = (next)=>{
 setTimeout(()=>{
  next()
 }, 2000)
}


somefunction('first')
somefunction('second')
```

I am trying to understand this and how the scopes are kept distinct. Most of googling cuncurrency etc.. leads to callback, promises, etc tutorials.. Can someone explain/point out to a reading material explaining the mechanism... Just thinking, is somefunction instantiated again in memory for each call..?

Comment: `is somefunction instantiated again in memory for each call` Kind of. Each call has its own `LexicalEnvironment` (with separate bindings for each variable). This doesn't really have anything to do with asynchronousness though, it's just plain scoping/assignment/closure rules.

Comment: `is somefunction instantiated again in memory for each call`  No,  Javascript has something called closures, when a function is called the JS engine will capture the current scope, this is then bound to the function.   Newer JS engines with `let / const` can also bind to a block scope, not just a functional scope.

Comment: It doesn't matter if a function is sync or async in this case (considering that the delay is same). `next` is callback function that is called. It would be the same if there was just `next()` instead of `setTimeout(...)`.